# Can I have a folder in my ASP.NET MVC4 project that is a webforms project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I tried googling, I promise! I may not be asking the question the right way. We have an existing project that is webforms (.NET 3.5 I think). It's not really a VS solution, just a folder with this structure:

/

../App_Code

../bin

../pages

../global.asax

../this.html

../that.aspx

../web.config

In the "pages" folder is where we have a big ugly mess of .aspx pages and there code behind.

App_Code holds some helper classes and whatnot. They rest should be self explanatory.

Questions:

1. What is the best strategy to put this mess inside an mvc4 application?
2. What do I have to do with routing back and forth (i.e. from .cshtml pages to .aspx and back again)
3. Any other considerations?

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OneASPNETSneakPeekElegantWebFormsAndSnowballsInHell.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198242.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will just work.

You can mix and match any kind of ASP.Net stuff in one project.

The ASPX files will be accessible using their actual paths, just like pure WebForms project.
You can also call `MapPageRoute()` to apply routing to those files.

Comment: This is the best news I heard all week.. So nothing major to be concerned about mixing legacy garbage with shiny and new MVC4?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it.  I would recommend adding this to your routeConfig:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("pages/{*pathInfo}");
```

It may not be even absolutely necessary, but it'll keep the request from even attempting to be parsed out in the routecollection.  Just incase you have a page and a route rule that can collide.  We do this for our webservices which reside in our MVC 4 application (inherited from an older website project).

Comment: I have this exact scenario, but the IgnoreRoute does not work for me. =/ My WebForms project is totally different from my parent folder. the app shows a dll error.

Comment: Your scenario isn't the same, so you would need to modify the solution for your particular setup.  Based on your comment, it sounds like you have a webforms application where the original question was about a website project.  While similar, they are different.  You can merge both a webforms application and MVC as well quite easily as well.